# Reading/Writing to/from iPhone's Documents folder performance

Tags: ios, performance, directory, documents

I have got an iPhone application where I archive permanent data in the documents folder of the application (arrays, dictionaries). I read/write from and to the documents folder quite frequently and I would like to know whether this is considered a bad habit. Wouldn't it be better if I had a singleton class, read and write to arrays there and then, only when the application quits, write this data to the documents folder ? I do not see/feel any performance issues right now on my iPhone 5, but I wanted to know whether this is a bad practise.

Comment: Well there was just a good overall reference for reading/writing files in iOS: [Using NSFileManager](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/). It may be helpful to you in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

FLASH memory has limited write capability - a long time ago it was rated in some increment of thousands. Not sure where it is today.

That said, if your app is using the standard file system APIs, then the system is using the file cache, and you might open a file, read it then change it many times without the file system ever writing to flash. The system may sync to flash occasionally, but that process is opaque - no way to really know when or why iOS does it.

The UNIX APIs allow for syncing the file system cache to the storage system (iOS this is FLASH), but if you are not using that then you are probably not doing much I/O at all given what you say above.

Given the lack of Apple discouraging developers from writing to the file system, I for sure would not worry about this.

But, if you said you were writing gigabytes of image data every few minutes - well - that might be a problem.