# any downsides to writing the same file 1000's of times in iOS?

Tags: ios, file

I'm considering overwriting the same small file 1,000's - 100,000's of times in an iOS app. Are there any downsides to this, given that flash memory is rated for 1000's of writes (but not, say, 100,000's)?

Will the system file cache save me if I stick to standard `FileHandle` operations? (without me having to implement my own such cache)

This has been addressed before: [Reading/Writing to/from iPhone's Documents folder performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079483/reading-writing-to-from-iphones-documents-folder-performance/20082161#20082161)

Any new insights?

---

Update in response to some comments below: in general I agree with you that sometimes examining the choice of solution is more critical than helping with the proposed solution itself.

However, for this case, I feel the question is legit. Basically, it applies to any program where there is a small amount of very volatile data that needs to be persisted often: say, a position in a game, or a stock tick, or some counter, or the last key pressed, or something like that. It needs to be reliably read after process restart, so the app can pick up where it left off, hence the question:

Can I use the iOS file system for that? I know I can't write 10,000's of times to actual flash memory - that would burn it out. But will file system operations solve this for me, through some form of caching? Or do I need to do that myself, 'by hand'?

I sort of assume 'yes' (file system will solve) - otherwise other apps that do this (there must be some) would be burning out phones all the time! But: hard to know for sure...

---

Update again: asked this question on apple forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116740

Still no clear answer. Some answers are: just cache it yourself to avoid any such potential problems (and there can be: a file write can fail, and increasing the frequency increases the probability of failure in weird ways). Another is: iOS logs so much stuff, there's no way I can write more frequently than that, and that's fine, so no worries... I guess I'll leave this question open for now.

Comment: Why do you have to do this? Is there any need to persist the data continuously?

Comment: Does it matter? I think I have some use case for it, and am trying to find out if it'll hurt me.

Comment: I’m asking because writing to memory and writing occasionally to the file might perform better, and would take better care of the device’s hardware.

Comment: Well, that's the question I guess - does the system perform this type of caching, with only occasional writing to actual flash memory, in such a way that I shouldn't even worry about it.

Comment: I guess it should. Apple doesn’t release the specifications for their flash chips, so I don’t think there’s a way to know for sure.

Comment: There's a reason [NS]UserDefaults only writes to disk occasionally. Back in the iOS 2.0 days the iOS (iPhoneOS then) documentation suggested to avoid writing to disk too often. Of course the SSD storage is much better now than it was on the iPhone 3G.

Comment: Per your response to @RenzoTissoni. It could be worth explaining the use case (even if anonymized to protect your idea). XY Problems (http://xyproblem.info) happen all the time, so if you’re asking a question that feels weird (it does), it’s worth us asking if your approach is really the best solution to your problem.

Comment: @Nate addressed your comments in update above...